# Webserver force X-FRAME-OPTIONS SAMEORIGIN

Tags: iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, iis-8, x-frame-options

After an windows update on our windows web server IIS 8 it, iframe of the hosted sharepoint 2013 stopped working from an external domain.

The server seems to force X-FRAME-OPTIONS SAMEORIGIN. This value is not set in web.config or in IIS Manager under HTTP Response Header.

I've tried to add a HTTP Response header in both IIS Manager and in web.config but it doesnt help.
If i dont add anything i get this error:

```
Refused to display 'http://SP-SITE' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

When i add the X-FRAME-OPTIONS ALLOW-FROM http://Other-url i get this error:

```
Refused to display 'http://SP-SITE' in a frame because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('SAMEORIGIN, ALLOW-FROM http://Other-URL, ALLOW-FROM http://Other-URL'). Falling back to 'deny'.
```

Does anyone know how i should find where the SAMEORIGIN value is set or how to override it or change it?

Comment: This is a SharePoint by design change I think, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4531668/cannot-display-sharepoint-pages-from-a-different-domain-in-iframe